# When I turn off the internet connection it's not showing false value from NetInfo.isConnect function

Tags: reactjs, react-native, networking

When I turn off my internet connection from my real device it is not detecting that I am offline, however when again come online it is return the value to true.

```
import React from 'react';
import {
  SafeAreaView,
  StyleSheet,
  View,
  Text,
  StatusBar,
  Image,
  TouchableOpacity,
  FlatList,
  NetInfo
} from 'react-native';

export default class App extends React.Component {
    componentDidMount() {
        NetInfo.isConnected.addEventListener('connectionChange',
        this.handleConnectivityChange);  
    }

    componentWillUnmount() {
        NetInfo.isConnected.removeEventListener('connectionChange', 
        this.handleConnectivityChange);
    }
    handleConnectivityChange = (isConnected) => {
        console.log(isConnected ? 'connected':'not connected')
    }
```

As of now , I am not mentioning render () here.

Answer (score 5):

**Use [React Native Community's `NetInfo`](https://github.com/react-native-community/react-native-netinfo) because [RN's version is deprecated](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/netinfo.html)**.

RNC version would only accept a callback when adding the listener.

It should be:

```
import NetInfo from "@react-native-community/netinfo";

export default class App extends React.Component {

  constructor(props) {
    super(props)
    this.unsubscribe = null
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    this.unsubscribe = NetInfo.addEventListener(
      this.handleConnectivityChange
    );
  }

  componentWillUnmount() {
    this.unsubscribe();
  }

  handleConnectivityChange = (state) => {
    console.log(state.isConnected ? 'connected': 'not connected')
  }

  render() {...}
}
```

Comment: When I use NetInfo from "@react-native-community/netinfo"; i always get warning saying: the version of Netinfo is deprecated. however using NetInfo from 'react-native' does not throw any warning.

Comment: Really sorry, actually I am using NetInfo from "@react-native-community/netinfo";

Comment: Don't be sorry. I'm here to help. So have you checked the link: https://github.com/react-native-community/react-native-netinfo/issues/123?

Comment: Is there is any generic component, from where we can handle netIfo throughout the App.?

Comment: You don't need to bind function into constructore when you do array function :)

Comment: @egzonszo, thanks! updated without binding due to arrow function.